# Error while Inserting record through node into MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am new in Node and trying to develop some initial apps. I am currently inserting record into database(MySQL) through Node. My post method is like

```
router.post('/add',function(req,res){
    connection.connect();
    var firstName = req.body.FirstName;
    var lastName = req.body.LastName;
    students.push({
        //id: studentList.length+1,
        FirstName: firstName,
        LastName: lastName
    });
    var post  = {FirstName: firstName, LastName: lastName};
    connection.query('INSERT INTO tblstudent VALUES ? ', post,function(err,result){
        if (err) {
                res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
            }
    });
    res.redirect('/');
    connection.end();
});
```

where Id is another column but auto incremented, so I trying to insert record. I'm having the following error.

[image]

Comment: Please look into this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent

Answer (score 1):

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

This error means that headers where already set but one more is trying to be set up.

In your case, you have called `res.redirect()`, making the response finished. Then your code threw an error because query has failed, and you`ve tried to set a response: 
"res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");".

In order to fix the problem you should move `res.redirect('/');` in to callback function of the query.

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO tblstudent VALUES ? ', post,function(err,result){
    if (err) {
            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
});
```